# Call methods on a fragment when clearing the back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm developing an Android application with fragments. These fragments are lists of items. When the user selects an item, a new fragment is added to the stack.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.frameContent, ListFragment.newInstance(TypeEnum.comunidades,
                                  resultsvalue.get(position).getIdentificador(),
                                  resultsvalue.get(position).getIdentificador(),
                                  resultsvalue.get(position).getNombre()))
                                  .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The user has the option to go back (to previous list), but when I go back to the previous fragment no lifecycle method is called. When I'm adding a new fragment, the fragment below does not execute `onPause()` nor `onStop()`, so when go back to the fragment below the top of the stack I have no callback to run methods.

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: Why it isn't running any life cycle method when the fragment returns to the top of the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood your question, you are saying that when going back to the main fragment, it is somewhat not initialized because it wasn't destroyed before.

In this case I believe you want to use `replace()` rather than `add()`. That way the replaced fragment will go through the destroy process, calling both onPause / onStop.

Calling methods on your still-alive fragment can be done as follows:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
MainFragment f = (MainFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TAG");
f.doSomething();
```

You can specify your tag when you first add the main fragment to the container.

Comment: And Is it not possible to use 'add' and when the fragment back to the top execute some method?

Comment: With replace(), when you go back, you can just put your method inside onStart() or onResume() and it will be called. Maybe I didn't understand your question.

Comment: I need to change a information in fragment if the user come back. And I need to use 'add' because I want that the list is in the same position as before click.

Comment: Thaks!! And... How do I know which fragment is on top of the stack?

Comment: You can use FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() to get the stack size and FragmentManger.getBackStackEntry(size).

Comment: FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() always is 0

Comment: Then there is no fragment in the backstack.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace()` instead of `add()`.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContent, ListFragment.newInstance(TypeEnum.comunidades, resultsvalue.get(position).getIdentificador(), resultsvalue.get(position).getIdentificador(), resultsvalue.get(position).getNombre())).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: I need to change a information in fragment if the user come back. And I need to use 'add' because I want that the list is in the same position as before click.